# ITEM_UPLOAD in Box API

Tags: box-api

The ITEM_UPLOAD event is generated by Box API every time when new version of the file is uploaded.
But it seems there is no linkage between ITEM_UPLOAD event and version number of the uploaded file (I would like track every change in the uploaded file to check who and when re-uploaded it and able to get content of every version of the file using ITEM_UPLOAD event).
The "source" of the ITEM_UPLOAD event contains information about uploaded file, but version number is not there.

Does any solution or workaround exist here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call the GET /files//versions and get a full list of the versions of the file at any time.  The events that are generated generally only include basic information about the item.  If you want more details you often have to make an additional API call to get that information.

Consider your question a submitted feature request though.  We will look into whether it would be easy for us to include the version number in the event.  If it is, we'll add it in.